# Two quick Mathematica Questions about the dictionary

Tags: assignment

Question1:
Get the list of pairs of the form {language,number of words in dictionary}. Call this list langlength

What I did was this:

```
langlength = 
  {{Arabic, Length[DictionaryLookup[{"Arabic", All}]]}, 
   {BrazilianPortuguese, Length[DictionaryLookup[{"BrazilianPortuguese", All}]]}, 
   {Breton, Length[DictionaryLookup[{"Breton", All}]]},......}
```

And so on.  What's a shorter way of doing this?

---

Question2:
Look at all the words contained in all the dictionaries. What are the ones of maximum length?

I had:

```
Max[StringLength[lang]]
```

But that's not working and not sure what's missing.

Please help me with either or both questions.

---

I set lang = DictionaryLookup[All]

Comment: Is it homework?

Comment: What did you use for `lang`?

Comment: I have the first question, I just need the second question now.  I need to find a way to show the longest word of each language.  So if I know the longest word in English was 23, I have to find a way to see what THAT word is.

Answer (score 3):

This could be automated:

```
languages = DictionaryLookup[All];
leng = Length /@ (DictionaryLookup[{#, All}] & /@ languages)
```

The longest words could be extracted:

```
longw = 
  Last /@ (SortBy[#, StringLength[#] &] & /@ (DictionaryLookup[{#, All}] & /@ languages))
```

(noting that there may be more than one word of equal maximal length). You can adapt to sut your goal, e.g tabulate language and dictionary length:

```
Thread[{languages, leng}] // TableForm
```

Comment: I have the max length of each language, I just need a way to find what words they are exactly.

Comment: For the second question, I need to find a way to show the longest word of each language.  So for example, if I know the longest word in English was 23, I have to find a way to see what that 23 letter word is.

Comment: @Sam  `longw` in the code above is a list of the longest words. You could tabulate language, longest word and length as follows: `Thread[{languages,longw,StringLength/@longw}]//TableForm`